# remove horizontal scrolling on Winedt

Tags: winedt

Something went wrong with my Winedt 9.0 editor, and now the horizontal scrolling option is enabled, and it is killing me.

I have tried to look at options > preferences, but could not find a way to remove the horizontal scrolling.

Would be glad for a hint here.[image: no multilines]
[image: the wrapping preferences]

Comment: In the `editor` tab,there's a `Enable Scroll Lock Key` checkbox.maybe it has something to see with your problem. B. t. w., why didn't you update to version 10.1?

Comment: I do not see an editor tab, only 'edit'..

Comment: Of course my version is 10.1, but I can't believe there's no equivalent in version 9.0, perhaps under another name. This tab contains the `Undo buffer size` value.

Comment: It turns out that I have already tried, but it is does not work.

Comment: If you haven't changed too much the default settings, you might list you changes, ask to rebuild the default settings and rewrite your modifications. Or you might subscribe, if not already done, to WinEdt mailing list (winedt+list-subscribe@wsg.net) and ask for assistance. They're very efficient

Comment: Maybe your keyboard has scroll lock enabled...

Comment: If you mean that pressing the arrow keys up and down only scrolls the document up and down without moving the cursor, there's only one explanation: you have the Scroll Lock key enabled in your keyboard. If, with "the vertical scrolling option is enabled" you mean something else, let me know and I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: @karlkoeller I am sorry, I meant to say horizontal. The scroll lock is not enabled.

Comment: Check in Options -> Preferences -> Wrapping tab, if "Use fixed right margin" is enabled. If yes, tell me what the value of "Fixed Right Margin" is.

Comment: @karlkoeller it is not enabled, and the value is 78.

Comment: @karlkoeller I have attached a picture that decribes the problem.

Comment: This is because there is no break point in your lines.....

Comment: @karlkoeller In previous documents this was the same: There was no new line but the lines in the editor were not infinite.

Comment: I think OP wants visible line breaks.  So all As spread over multiple lines.

Comment: You are not talking about scrolling in my opinion, but wrapping. In Options -> Preferences -> Wrapping, is TeX listed in "Enable Wrapping for Modes"? If not, add it at the beginning. Same if you want soft wrapping, check the field "Use Soft Wrapping for Modes".

Comment: Both are applied. I have added these properties above.

Comment: Please contact me privately at webmaster@winedt.org (text only).